# Paho connectionLost never firing

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

Following is my code:

```
 public void connect() throws MqttException {
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName("user");
        options.setPassword("pass".toCharArray());
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://broker:8884", MqttClient.generateClientId(), handlerPahoDirs());
        client.setCallback(callback);
        client.connect(options);
        client.subscribe(this.topic);
    }
```

and `connectionLost` on **MqttCallback**:

```
 public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
            try {
                connect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                //Logger
            }
        }
```

It turns out that the `connectionLost()` is never gets called! Sometimes I disconnected the internet and none of this method was called (I was in debug mode). What can it be?

Comment: How long did you leave it after disconnecting to see if the `connectionLost` was fired?

Comment: Some minutes. Like 5, or something like that.

Comment: Calling connectionLost() will only happen after the TCP timeout has expired.  On a lot of systems, the default value for timeout is 2 hours.  https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows